# What is the number of combination of a nested loop with a sum of 100 and changing values of step, up and down limit for each variable?

Tags: r, combinations, nested-loops, coding-efficiency

I'm working with a nested-loop that add a line in an array at each step.
There are 6 loops and 8 variables.

- a,b,c,d,e,f are the index for the loop. Each of them can take a value between a define down limit and a define up limit include in (0:100) with a known step value.
- g takes also a value between a down and up limit in (0:100) with a known step value
- output : is a value calculated with a,b,c,d,e,f,g

The sum(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) must always be 100.

When I'm using a small step like 1 or 0.1. It takes a lot of time to run because I'm using rbind. So I would like to pre-allocate and use an other function, however, I don't know the size of the final table as I would like to change the step, the down and the up limit for each variable a,b,c,d,e,f,g. Do you have an idea of an equation to find the number of combination in function of those parameters?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
combinaison_array<-array(NA,dim= c(1,8)) # define the storage array

for (a in seq(from=0, to=100, by=25)){ 
  for (b in seq(from=25, to=100-a, by=25)){ 
    for (c in seq(from=0, to=100-a-b, by=25)){ 
      for (d in seq(from=0, to=100-a-b-c, by=25)){ 
        for (e in seq(from=0, to=100-a-b-c-d, by=50)){ 
          for (f in seq(from=0, to=100-a-b-c-d-e, by=25)){ 
            g=100-a-b-c-d-e-f
            output=5*(a+b+c)*(d+e+f)
            combinaison_array<- 
            rbind(combinaison_array,c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,output))}}}}}}
View(combinaison_array)
```

I have also the problem that if b,c,d,e,f begins from an other value than 0, there is a wrong sign in by in Error in seq.default(from = 25, to = 100 - a, by = 25). But I think the output array is still right. What do you think about that ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Running the code gives me an error because there is a wrong sign in `by` in `Error in seq.default(from = 25, to = 100 - a, by = 25) :`. Probably same is true for the other `seq` functions but this is the first to cause the error

Comment: @ schwantke Yes I have this error too and I don't know how to solve it because I think the output array is correct. If  you put a 0 in from for b. The error diseapears.

Comment: Are the step values the same for all the variables? Also, you have to realize, it is possible that there may not be a suitable set of solutions if there are too many constraints.

Comment: @ Rohit I would like to have the smallest step as possible so if I could have a step of 0.1 for all is could be very great. But maybe it is too long to run this is why I propose to have different values of step for each variable as the ouput value is more sensible for some values than the other (in my real program not in this exemple).

Comment: @AlexisLB If you want to go from 0:100 in steps of 0.1 for 7 variables, then even with the sum constraint, it will have roughly 1000^6 or 10^18 possible combinations of 7 numbers. You don't have enough memory for that. Thats exabytes of memory.

Comment: I see @Rohit so I will run it a first time with a bigger value of step for exemple a step of 2 for a,b,e,f with a up limit of 100 and a step of 0.5 for c,d with a uplimit of 50. Than I will run it again with little values of step but with more contrainous values of up and down limit in function of the result of output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way I can think of is using `expnd.grid()` to list all possible combinations of the variables based on the range. Then you can filter based on the sum constraint. Note that this will use a lot of memory because you will generate the full grid instead of just the required subset before filtering.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

range_list <- list( # Individual variable ranges
  a=seq(0,100,1),
  b=seq(25,100,25),
  c=seq(0,100,5),
  d=seq(0,50,5)
)


comb_array <- expand.grid(range_list) %>% # All possible combinations
  mutate(s=rowSums(.))%>%
  filter(s==100) %>% # Filter by sum constraint
  select(-s) %>% # Remove sum variable
  arrange_all() # Sort by all columns(optional)

comb_array
#>      a   b  c  d
#> 1    0  25 25 50
#> 2    0  25 30 45
#> 3    0  25 35 40
#> 4    0  25 40 35
#> 5    0  25 45 30
#> 6    0  25 50 25
#> 7    0  25 55 20
#> 8    0  25 60 15
#> 9    0  25 65 10
#> 10   0  25 70  5
#> 11   0  25 75  0
#> 12   0  50  0 50
#> 13   0  50  5 45
#> 14   0  50 10 40
#> 15   0  50 15 35
#> 16   0  50 20 30
#> 17   0  50 25 25
#> 18   0  50 30 20
#> 19   0  50 35 15
#> 20   0  50 40 10
#> 21   0  50 45  5
#> 22   0  50 50  0
#> 23   0  75  0 25
#> 24   0  75  5 20
#> 25   0  75 10 15
#> 26   0  75 15 10
#> 27   0  75 20  5
#> 28   0  75 25  0
#> 29   0 100  0  0
#> 30   5  25 20 50
#> 31   5  25 25 45
#> 32   5  25 30 40
#> 33   5  25 35 35
#> 34   5  25 40 30
#> 35   5  25 45 25
#> 36   5  25 50 20
#> 37   5  25 55 15
#> 38   5  25 60 10
#> 39   5  25 65  5
#> 40   5  25 70  0
#> 41   5  50  0 45
#> 42   5  50  5 40
#> 43   5  50 10 35
#> 44   5  50 15 30
#> 45   5  50 20 25
#> 46   5  50 25 20
#> 47   5  50 30 15
#> 48   5  50 35 10
#> 49   5  50 40  5
#> 50   5  50 45  0
#> 51   5  75  0 20
#> 52   5  75  5 15
#> 53   5  75 10 10
#> 54   5  75 15  5
#> 55   5  75 20  0
#> 56  10  25 15 50
#> 57  10  25 20 45
#> 58  10  25 25 40
#> 59  10  25 30 35
#> 60  10  25 35 30
#> 61  10  25 40 25
#> 62  10  25 45 20
#> 63  10  25 50 15
#> 64  10  25 55 10
#> 65  10  25 60  5
#> 66  10  25 65  0
#> 67  10  50  0 40
#> 68  10  50  5 35
#> 69  10  50 10 30
#> 70  10  50 15 25
#> 71  10  50 20 20
#> 72  10  50 25 15
#> 73  10  50 30 10
#> 74  10  50 35  5
#> 75  10  50 40  0
#> 76  10  75  0 15
#> 77  10  75  5 10
#> 78  10  75 10  5
#> 79  10  75 15  0
#> 80  15  25 10 50
#> 81  15  25 15 45
#> 82  15  25 20 40
#> 83  15  25 25 35
#> 84  15  25 30 30
#> 85  15  25 35 25
#> 86  15  25 40 20
#> 87  15  25 45 15
#> 88  15  25 50 10
#> 89  15  25 55  5
#> 90  15  25 60  0
#> 91  15  50  0 35
#> 92  15  50  5 30
#> 93  15  50 10 25
#> 94  15  50 15 20
#> 95  15  50 20 15
#> 96  15  50 25 10
#> 97  15  50 30  5
#> 98  15  50 35  0
#> 99  15  75  0 10
#> 100 15  75  5  5
#> 101 15  75 10  0
#> 102 20  25  5 50
#> 103 20  25 10 45
#> 104 20  25 15 40
#> 105 20  25 20 35
#> 106 20  25 25 30
#> 107 20  25 30 25
#> 108 20  25 35 20
#> 109 20  25 40 15
#> 110 20  25 45 10
#> 111 20  25 50  5
#> 112 20  25 55  0
#> 113 20  50  0 30
#> 114 20  50  5 25
#> 115 20  50 10 20
#> 116 20  50 15 15
#> 117 20  50 20 10
#> 118 20  50 25  5
#> 119 20  50 30  0
#> 120 20  75  0  5
#> 121 20  75  5  0
#> 122 25  25  0 50
#> 123 25  25  5 45
#> 124 25  25 10 40
#> 125 25  25 15 35
#> 126 25  25 20 30
#> 127 25  25 25 25
#> 128 25  25 30 20
#> 129 25  25 35 15
#> 130 25  25 40 10
#> 131 25  25 45  5
#> 132 25  25 50  0
#> 133 25  50  0 25
#> 134 25  50  5 20
#> 135 25  50 10 15
#> 136 25  50 15 10
#> 137 25  50 20  5
#> 138 25  50 25  0
#> 139 25  75  0  0
#> 140 30  25  0 45
#> 141 30  25  5 40
#> 142 30  25 10 35
#> 143 30  25 15 30
#> 144 30  25 20 25
#> 145 30  25 25 20
#> 146 30  25 30 15
#> 147 30  25 35 10
#> 148 30  25 40  5
#> 149 30  25 45  0
#> 150 30  50  0 20
#> 151 30  50  5 15
#> 152 30  50 10 10
#> 153 30  50 15  5
#> 154 30  50 20  0
#> 155 35  25  0 40
#> 156 35  25  5 35
#> 157 35  25 10 30
#> 158 35  25 15 25
#> 159 35  25 20 20
#> 160 35  25 25 15
#> 161 35  25 30 10
#> 162 35  25 35  5
#> 163 35  25 40  0
#> 164 35  50  0 15
#> 165 35  50  5 10
#> 166 35  50 10  5
#> 167 35  50 15  0
#> 168 40  25  0 35
#> 169 40  25  5 30
#> 170 40  25 10 25
#> 171 40  25 15 20
#> 172 40  25 20 15
#> 173 40  25 25 10
#> 174 40  25 30  5
#> 175 40  25 35  0
#> 176 40  50  0 10
#> 177 40  50  5  5
#> 178 40  50 10  0
#> 179 45  25  0 30
#> 180 45  25  5 25
#> 181 45  25 10 20
#> 182 45  25 15 15
#> 183 45  25 20 10
#> 184 45  25 25  5
#> 185 45  25 30  0
#> 186 45  50  0  5
#> 187 45  50  5  0
#> 188 50  25  0 25
#> 189 50  25  5 20
#> 190 50  25 10 15
#> 191 50  25 15 10
#> 192 50  25 20  5
#> 193 50  25 25  0
#> 194 50  50  0  0
#> 195 55  25  0 20
#> 196 55  25  5 15
#> 197 55  25 10 10
#> 198 55  25 15  5
#> 199 55  25 20  0
#> 200 60  25  0 15
#> 201 60  25  5 10
#> 202 60  25 10  5
#> 203 60  25 15  0
#> 204 65  25  0 10
#> 205 65  25  5  5
#> 206 65  25 10  0
#> 207 70  25  0  5
#> 208 70  25  5  0
#> 209 75  25  0  0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>